# How to check if a Terms' argument is part of a list?

Tags: list, prolog

So I'm writing a knapsack problem and in my task there's a specification, that there can't be the same "weight" Item in a knapsack.

Basically I send my Items list, which is "Pantry", then the capacity, of how many weight there can be inside the Knapsack and the Knapsack itself.

```
legalKnapsackNoSameRocks(Pantry, Capacity, Knapsack):-
   subseq2(Knapsack,Pantry),
   weight(Knapsack,W),
   W =< Capacity.
```

Then I make subLists of all possible combinations

```
subseq2([],[]).
subseq2([Item | RestX], [Item | RestY]) :-
   not(member(arg(2, Item, X), L)),
   add_tail(L, arg(2, Item, X), L),
   subseq2(RestX,RestY).
subseq2(X, [_ | RestY]) :-
   subseq2(X,RestY).
```

And inside making the subLists I have to check if the list contains a weight that the next Item has, and if so, then I don't put the same weight item in the list.

The way I think of doing it, is making a new list, where I add the "Weight" of the Items. So basically I check if the "Weights" list contains the "Weight" of an Item that I want to put in the Knapsack and if so, I don't put it in.

I've made a "append" predicate as well

```
add_tail([],X,[X]).
add_tail([H|T],X,[H|L]):- add_tail(T,X,L).
```

But it never returns anything, its always false. I assume that it's because the list is empty in the first place? Thank you.

EDIT:

Weight predicate gets the Knapsack and adds all the weights of all items and returns the total weight.

When I run the program I type

```
knapsackOptimizationWithoutSameSizeRocks(
   [ rock(smallRock,2,2300), 
     rock(biggerRock,4,6700),
     rock(mediumRock,3,6900),
     rock(smallDiamond,2,9200), 
     rock(smallDiamond,2, 9200),
     rock(smallDiamond, 3, 10000)
   ], 15 ,Knapsack).
```

Full code:

```
rock(smallDiamond,2,9200).
rock(smallRock,2,2300).
rock(biggerRock,4,6700).
rock(mediumRock,3,6900).
rock(smallDiamond,3, 10000).

knapsackOptimizationWithoutSameSizeRocks(Pantry, Capacity, Knapsack) :-
   allLegalKnapsacksNoSameRocks(Pantry, Capacity, R),
   maximumvalue(R, Knapsack),
   value(Knapsack, CALS),
   nl,print('value: '), print(CALS),
   !.

weight([],0).
weight([rock(_,W,_) | Rest], X) :-
  weight(Rest,RestW),
  X is W + RestW.

value([],0).
value([rock(_,_,C) | Rest], X) :-
  value(Rest,RestC),
  X is C + RestC.

subseq2([],[]).
subseq2([Item | RestX], [Item | RestY]) :-  
  %not(memberchk(arg(2, Item, X), [rock(_, L, _) | Rest])),

  %add_tail(L, arg(2, Item, X), L),
  %not(memberchk(Item, RestY)),
  subseq2(RestX,RestY).
subseq2(X, [_ | RestY]) :-
  subseq2(X,RestY).

%add_tail([],X,[X]).
%add_tail([H|T],X,[H|L]):- add_tail(T,X,L).

legalKnapsackNoSameRocks(Pantry, Capacity, Knapsack):-
  subseq2(Knapsack,Pantry),
  weight(Knapsack,W),
  W =< Capacity.

allLegalKnapsacksNoSameRocks(Pantry, Capacity, ListOfLegalKnapsacks) :-
   findall(LegalKnapsack,
             legalKnapsackNoSameRocks(Pantry, Capacity, LegalKnapsack),
          ListOfLegalKnapsacks).               

maximumvalue([LEGAL | LEGALS], MAXCALS) :-
   value(LEGAL, CALS),
   maxCals(LEGALS, CALS, LEGAL, MAXCALS).

maxCals([], MAXCALS, MAXCALLEGAL, MAXCALLEGAL).
maxCals([LEGAL | LEGALS], MAXCALS, MAXCALLEGAL, OUTPUT) :-
   value(LEGAL, NEWCALS), NEWCALS > MAXCALS,
   maxCals(LEGALS, NEWCALS, LEGAL,OUTPUT).
maxCals([LEGAL | LEGALS], MAXCALS, MAXCALLEGAL, OUTPUT) :-
   value(LEGAL, NEWCALS), NEWCALS =< MAXCALS,
   maxCals(LEGALS, MAXCALS, MAXCALLEGAL, OUTPUT).
```

I want to get something like

```
Knapsack = [rock(biggerRock, 4, 6700), rock(smallDiamond, 2, 9200), 
rock(smallDiamond, 3, 10000)].
```

Because those are all different weights, but this Knapsack combination has more value than this:

```
Knapsack = [rock(biggerRock, 4, 6700), rock(mediumRock, 3, 6900), 
rock(smallDiamond, 2, 9200)].
```

And if I could put same weights multiple times, it would give

```
Knapsack = [rock(biggerRock, 4, 6700), rock(mediumRock, 3, 6900), 
rock(smallDiamond, 2, 9200), rock(smallDiamond, 2, 9200),
 rock(smallDiamond, 3, 10000)].
```

Comment: `add_tail(L, arg(2, Item, X), L)` fails because it says that `L`  and `L` with `arg(2, Item, X)` appended are the same thing, which is impossible for a non-cyclic list. In other words, `add_tail(L, arg(2, Item, X), L)` says that if you take `L` and append ` arg(2, Item, X)` you get `L` again.

Comment: @TomasBy how could I check it? Weight predicate just adds all the weights of Items inside the knapsack that's given to it.

Comment: Okay... no you don't need to worry about the whole list, just say (something like) `\+ member(rock(_,_,W),Pantry)`.

Comment: @TomasBy posted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write `legalKnapsackNoSameRocks/3` like this:

```
legalKnapsackNoSameRocks(Pantry, Capacity, Knapsack) :-
  permutation(Pantry,RandomPantry),
  lknsr(RandomPantry,Capacity,[],Knapsack),
  weight(Knapsack,W),
  W =< Capacity.

lknsr([R|Rs],C,Ls0,Ls) :-
  R = rock(_,W,_),
  ( \+ member(rock(_,W,_),Ls0) ->
    Ls1 = [R|Ls0]
  ; Ls1 = Ls0 ),
  lknsr(Rs,C,Ls1,Ls).
lknsr([],_,Ls,Ls).
```

Since `permutation/2` gives you all possible permutations of the list, and `findall/3` (in `allLegalKnapsacksNoSameRocks/3`) collects all the legal combinations, `maximumvalue/2` can select the subset with the highest value.

Comment: It works! 

But it throws error when I put in the capacity to let's say 5. Also could you comment the code a little bit? Thank you.

Comment: Ty for the help. Fixed the "issue". Permutation gives the same amount of elements, I used my own subList predicate and it works nicely.